# Flatten a multilevel doubly LinkedList in Python

Tags: python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

I am working on LeetCode problem [430. Flatten a Multilevel Doubly Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-a-multilevel-doubly-linked-list/):

> You are given a doubly linked list, which contains nodes that have a
> next pointer, a previous pointer, and an additional **child pointer**.
> This child pointer may or may not point to a separate doubly linked
> list, also containing these special nodes. These child lists may have
> one or more children of their own, and so on, to produce a **multilevel
> data structure** as shown in the example below.
>
> Given the `head` of the first level of the list, **flatten** the list so
> that all the nodes appear in a single-level, doubly linked list. Let
> `curr` be a node with a child list. The nodes in the child list should
> appear **after** `curr` and **before** `curr.next` in the flattened list.
>
> Return *the* `head` *of the flattened list. The nodes in the list must have
> **all** of their child pointers set to* `null`.

### My Approach

This is what I intended to do:

1. Traverse through the head node and wherever a child node appears, change the link of the current node to the child node.
2. Then, add all the nodes traversed to a separate LList (in my code it is `ll`). I have kept `dummy` at the head of the new LList.
3. While reaching at every child node, add that node address to a stack. So, when doing a `pop()` operation, the last child node added will be retrieved first.
4. After that, pop and iterate through that child node till `None` and add new nodes to new LList i.e. `ll`. Lastly, return `dummy.next`

#### My Code

```py
class Solution:
    def flatten(self, head: 'Optional[Node]') -> 'Optional[Node]':
        curr = head
        ll = dummy = ListNode(0)
        stack = []
        
        while curr:
            if curr.child:
                stack.append(curr)
                ll.next = curr
                curr.next = curr.child
            else:
                ll.next = curr
            ll = ll.next
            curr = curr.next
        
        while stack:
            curr_node = stack.pop()
            
            while curr_node:
                ll.next = curr_node
                ll = ll.next
                curr_node = curr_node.next
        return dummy.next
```

#### The Problem

I am getting a Time Limit Exceeded warning. Can someone please tell me if I am correct with my approach and where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your code is creating a cycle in the `ll` list. The node that you pop from the stack was already put in the `ll` list at the time you pushed that node on the stack. But you append it again to the `ll` list, making a cycle. And so `while curr_node:` is becoming an infinite loop.

The general idea for the algorithm is fine though, but push the *next* node on the stack, instead of the *current* node.

Furthermore, you should:

- Clear the `child` reference once you have processed it
- Adapt the `prev` references, so they are consistent with the changes to some of the `next` references. Remember: it is a doubly linked list you get and need to return.

I would not:

- Lag behind with a separate `ll` reference. You can just work with `curr`
- Use the `dummy` node. Although I understand its utility, once you have dealt with the case of the empty list (as a boundary case), there is really no benefit anymore

So here is how I would do it:

```
class Solution:
    def flatten(self, head: 'Optional[Node]') -> 'Optional[Node]':
        if not head:
            return
        stack = []
        current = head
        while current:
            if current.child:
                if current.next:
                    stack.append(current.next)
                current.next = current.child
                current.next.prev = current
                current.child = None
            elif not current.next and stack:
                current.next = stack.pop()
                current.next.prev = current
            current = current.next
        return head
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for an amazing and crisp solution.
The idea being :
1. pushing curr.next to stack and changing the link to child node.
2. clearing child reference and setting next element's prev to 'curr'.

After that,
1. when reaching at end of the dllist(current), pop nodes from stack.
2. Traverse through nodes till 'not current.next'. As soon as it reaches the end, again pop a new node.

Awesome in-place operation!

I am new to coding. Can you please explain to me the time and space complexity of your solution? I suppose it is O(1) for space complexity.

Comment: If n is the number of nodes, then time complexity is O(n). Space complexity is not O(1), because of the `stack`. The size needed for the stack is O(level), where level is the depth of `child` references.

Comment: Thanks :) 
So will this be O(k)?
I'm sorry for naive questions, I'm still learning time and space complexities.

Comment: Depends on how you define *k*... If it is the deepest level of `child` references, then we agree. I called it *level*.